# Not found error in laravel

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel-4, hosting

It worked perfectly on local. But in server only the home page was worked well.Other Url's shows Not found error. I set the apache document root to the Laravel public folder.  What is the solution?

If i add index.php in after the domain name,then the corresponding page will shown. But then then the css and js are broken.

Comment: Need more info about the issue

Comment: Sounds like a problem with .htaccess. Make sure you have the correct file in your public directory and htaccess is enabled

Comment: Or its rewrite module is not enabled.

Comment: I got the solution. It's the permission problem on server.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It's the permission problem on server. I changed the permission of the folder. Now it's work fine.